# Laravel 5.4 - Undefined variable: markdown

Tags: php, laravel, email

I am trying to send a simple email with Laravel. I have no problem sending a normal HTML email but when I try to use the markdown feature I keep getting the error

`Undefined variable: markdown`

I am not using any instance of a model in my email right now, I am just trying to get a simple markdown email first. Here is how I have everything set up.

Mail Controller

```
namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

class ProjectSubmitted extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        return $this->markdown('emails.project-submitted');
    }
}
```

Blade Template

```
@component('mail::message')
*Lorem Ipsum Dolor

@component('mail::button', ['url' => 'http://google.com'])
Lorem Ipsum Dolor
@endcomponent

Thanks,<br>
Lorem Ipsum
@endcomponent
```

That is all I have right now, very basic. When I try to send this email

`\Mail::to('example@example.com')->send( new \App\Mail\ProjectSubmitted );`

I keep getting the error `Undefined variable: markdown`. Cannot find anything on this. Any help would be amazing.

Comment: but where defined public $markdown ?

Comment: Have you configured artisan to use markdown `php artisan make:mail ProjectSubmitted --markdown=emails.project-submitted`, also don't you need to specify a from email?
https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/mail#markdown-mailables

Comment: @effy yes I made the controller using that artisan command.

Comment: how about use Laravel `Components & Slots` and pass data to your layout?

Comment: Also, tried `return $this->from('example@example.com')->markdown('emails.project-submitted');`

Comment: This might be an issue already reported [here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/19504) and fixed very recently [here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/19504/commits/2f6db9e9bcebaa00e15f58eedd686934b7d716d9).
I'm not sure though if this is the exact same error. Is the error you posted the full length error you're getting?

Comment: Where is markdown defined, and what version of Laravel are you using? The only place I see any markdown function or variable defined in 5.3 is in SlackAttachment

Comment: @effy that issue was the fix. Thank you so much for finding that! Everything is working now! Really wish they would patch that..

Comment: @TaylorFoster I'm posting my comment as an answer, Glad I could help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an issue already reported [here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/19504) and patched very recently [here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/19504/commits/2f6db9e9bcebaa00e15f58eedd686934b7d716d9).

A temporary fix can be applied by editing the `Mailable.php` file at the root of your project (/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Mail/Mailable.php).

Change line 195 to `'text' => $this->buildMarkdownText($markdown, $data)`, and line 222 to `protected function buildMarkdownText($markdown, $data)`.

Comment: This is 100% the correct fix if someone runs into this issue. Thanks again @effy.

Comment: @TaylorFoster Please clarify, do you need to wait for the patch to be applied or can you manually modify Mailable.php to fix this? If yes, I can also post the code snippets for the fix so that someone else stumbling across this doesn't need to follow the links...

Comment: From the project root, the path (laravel 5.4) `/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Mail/Mailable.php'